# Forking with Pipes C language vs Threading in Java

Tags: java, c

I'm currently comparing forking in C language and then threads in Java. I'm trying to understand how threads in the same process share memory, they don't need to communicate over a pipe. What would a java program version look like using threads? Is it even possible, sorry I'm still new to java.

My C program details:

Given a circle centered at (0,0) with radius 1 and a square bounding the circle (with side length 2), generate random points that fall within the square. π is approximately (4 x number of points in circle / total number of points), as the number of points approaches infinity.

This C program reads in a file. The file will contain the number of points in the it as the first line and the (x, y) float points on subsequent lines, one pair per line. Once it reads the file it splits up the work of calculating the Monte Carlo approximation evenly among the processes. Communication among the processes must be done with an unnamed pipe.

C code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct Point{
  double x;
  double y;
} Point;

int main(int argc, char *const argv[]){

  if(argc!=3){
    fprintf(stderr,"Wrong number of arguments\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  FILE *input=fopen(argv[1],"r");
  if(input==NULL){
      fprintf(stderr,"Can't open file %s\n",argv[1]);
      exit(1);
   }
   int nprocesses;
   if(sscanf(argv[2],"%d",&nprocesses)!=1){
      fprintf(stderr,"Bad number of processes\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   int npoints;
   if(fscanf(input,"%d",&npoints)!=1){
     fprintf(stderr,"Expecting number of points\n");
     exit(1);
   }
  Point *points=(Point *)malloc(npoints * sizeof(Point));//allocate memory for npoints
  for(int i=0;i < npoints;i++){
      double x, y;
      if(fscanf(input,"%f %f", &x, &y)!=2){
         fprintf(stderr,"Bad point\n");
         exit(1);
      }
      points[i].x=x;
      points[i].y=y;
  }
#if 0
  int ninsidecircle=0;
  for(int i =0; i < npoints; i++){
    double distance = sqrt((double)(points[i].x * points[i].x) + (double)(points[i].y * points[i].y));
    if(distance <= 1.0){
       ninsidecircle++;
    }
  }
#else
  int pipes[2];
  int rc=pipe(pipes);
  if(rc<0){
    fprintf(stderr,"Bad pipe.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  int pointsPerProcess=npoints/nprocesses;
  if(npoints % nprocesses != 0){
    pointsPerProcess++;
  }
  for(int process = 0; process < nprocesses; process++){
    int id=fork();
    if(id < 0){
      fprintf(stderr,"Can't fork.\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    if(id!=0){
      continue;
    }
    // this is the child
    close(pipes[0]);
    int ninsidecircle=0;
    int j=process*pointsPerProcess;
    int k=j+pointsPerProcess;
    if(j>npoints){
      j = npoints;
    }

    if(k>npoints){
      k = npoints;
    }
    for(int i=j; i<k; i++){
      double distance = sqrt((double)(points[i].x * points[i].x) + (double)(points[i].y * points[i].y));
      if(distance <= 1.0){
    ninsidecircle++;
      }
    }
    write(pipes[1],&ninsidecircle,sizeof(ninsidecircle));
    close(pipes[1]);
    exit(0);
  }
  int ninsidecircle=0;
  for(int process = 0; process<nprocesses; process++){
    int n;
    read(pipes[0],&n,sizeof(n));
    ninsidecircle+=n;
  }
  close(pipes[0]);
#endif
  printf("%d in circle, %d points, Pi is approximately %.5f\n",ninsidecircle,npoints, 4.0 * ninsidecircle / npoints);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the looks of it, the C program should use [threads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) too. It seems unnecessary to create separate processes and communicate through pipes.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to understand how threads in the same process share memory,
> they don't need to communicate over a pipe.

The reason is that **they're in the same process**.

This isn't a language issue.  Both Java and C programs can choose to use separate processes communicating over pipes, or a single process with multiple threads.  (Or indeed, a single process using pipes internally, though that's less common).

A process is:

- An address space
- A set of resources, like open file handles
- One or more threads of execution

Once you've got a single address space between multiple threads, you can share variables as much as you want, communicating in ad-hoc ways (and then the problem becomes putting a little formality in place to prevent unwanted simultaneous access).

Your homework problem could be solved with one process and a set of threads (see the [pthreads library](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html), for example), but it's asking you specifically for a multiprocess solution.  That's an aspect of the homework, not of the programming language.

We can do exactly the same thing from Java - create separate processes and use pipes. See the [Process class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). But threads are often more convenient because of the shared address space.  Shared data is often easier than passing messages.

One difference is that, since Java is a newer language than C, threads are "built in" to a greater extent. So there's not so much history of "this is how we used to do it" to overcome.